# Segmentation fault on c++ minsweeper prototype

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am a new programming student just learning c++. I am working on a minesweeper clone for an assignment, but I am running into a segmentation fault. I don't know which line it's occurring on, as I am running the program in puTTy and writing it in emacs. Do either of these offer some function to locate segmentation faults that I am unaware of?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int ROWS = 9;
const int COLS = 26;

void populate_board(int array[][COLS]);
void print_board(int array[][COLS]);


int main(){
  int choice;
  int targets[ROWS][COLS];
  int guessed_spaces[ROWS][COLS];

  populate_board(targets);
  do{
    cout << "Press '0' to exit." << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    switch(choice){
      case 0:
        break;
      default:
        print_board(targets);
    }
  }while (choice !=0);
}


void populate_board(int targets[][COLS]){
  int row = 0;
  int col = 0;


  for(row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
    for(col = 0; col < COLS; row++){
      srand (time(NULL));
      int random = rand() % 2;
      targets[row][col] = random;
    }
  }
}


void print_board(int targets[][COLS]){
  int row = 0;
  int col = 0;

  for(row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
    cout << row << "|";
    for(col = 0; col < COLS; col++){
      cout << targets[row][col] << " ";
    }
    cout << "|" << endl;
  }
  cout << "  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -" << endl;
  cout << "  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Run the program in a debugger.  It will straight away tell you where the segfault is.

Comment: Warning: Under just about all circumstances you want to call `srand` only once somewhere near the start of `main`. If you find yourself in one of those rare cases where you need to call `srand` more than once, you probably should consider using a different random number generator.

Comment: I'm guessing you are on a unix machine assuming it has gcc as a compiler it probably also has the gdb debugger. Make sure to compile your program with the -g switch to include debugging information.

Answer (score 3):

Here :

```
for(row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
{
    for(col = 0; col < COLS; row++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int random = rand() % 2;
        targets[row][col] = random;
    }
}
```

You are incrementing `row` twice, both in inner and outer loop. So it will go beyond of `targets` bounds. You need to change it to :

```
for(row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
{
    for(col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int random = rand() % 2;
        targets[row][col] = random;
    }
}
```